# Thread synchronization in C#?

Tags: c#, sqlite, multithreading

I have lots of few small functions, each executes a query. I want only one function to be running at a time, what is the best possible way of thread sync to avoid database locked issue in SQLite (C#).

The functions are in multiple classes, how will you lock all the functions in all the DB classes, so that only one function from any of the DB class gets executed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll play devil's advocate... why do you want to invoke them in separate threads if only one will be executing at a time? I would just put the work items into a Queue and have a single thread read off the queue one at a time.

EDIT:
As per my comment below, here is an example of a helper class you could use to refactor your data access into a more centralized place. It's a very basic example and not tested.

```
class Database {
    private string connectionString;
    private readonly object syncRoot = new object();

    public Database(string connectionString) {
        this.connectionString = connectionString;
    }

    public void ExecuteReader(SqlCommand command, Action<IDataRecord> forEachRow) {
        lock (syncRoot) {
            using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) {
                command.Connection = connection;
                connection.Open();

                using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader()) {
                    while (reader.Read()) {
                        forEachRow(reader);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

var myDB = new Database("connection string");
var myCommand = new SqlCommand("select id from blah");
myDB.ExecuteReader(myCommand, row => Console.WriteLine("ID: {0}", row["id"]));
```

Comment: Its not deliberate multi-threading, I am getting db locked issues. The thread may be due to invoke or any other things. There are lots of places where DB is used, and sync all using Queue will be a tough job.

Comment: You may want to consider refactoring your data access into a helper class which would be easier to guard against such re-entry. Trying to coordinate your locks across multiple classes will get unwieldy very quickly. I'll put a quick example in my answer.

Comment: looks pretty cool to me, many thanks, let me try this back and get back to you, in case of any issues.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to have a common object and lock that object using c# lock() keyword.  However I find this to be little cumbersome to manage on large projects and often have used [wait handles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.waithandle.aspx).

I would have a function that gets the connection to the DB and then a release that must be called to signal the wait handle.  On the get to the connection you could try wait to throw an error rather then have a deadlock.

Comment: the functions are in multiple classes, how will you lock all the functions in all the DB classes, so that only one function from any of the DB class gets executed.

Comment: The object you are locking could be a global static class I suppose.

Answer (score 2):

To add onto rerun's answer, you'll want code that looks like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private readonly object lockObject = new object();

    public void MyMethod()
    {
        lock (lockObject)
        {
            // Do stuff
        }
    }

    public void AnotherMethod()
    {
        lock (lockObject)
        {
            // Do stuff
        }
    }
}
```

Jon Skeet has an excellent threading series: http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/threads/

Comment: @Bolia: I think we're going to need more information. It sounds like a bad design to me to have separate classes operating on the database and trying to keep them all apart like this.